# When is the winning condition checked in Fluxx?

Tags: fluxx

New Rule "Draw 4" is in play.

One opponent changes the Goal to "10 cards in hand".

I have six cards in my hand. It's my turn and I draw four cards.

I contend that the game is now over, as I have met the winning condition. (I don't have any Creepers.)

Another opponent says "no, you have to finish your turn".

Who is correct?

I don't see how he can be right. For one thing you can win on someone else's turn assuming you have the winning combo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You won.**

From the Fluxx [rules](http://wunderland.com/LooneyLabs/Fluxx/Rules3.0.html):

> **Winning the Game**
>
> The game continues until one player meets the conditions of the current Goal. That player wins immediately, regardless of whose turn it is.

The word 'immediately' doesn't match with what your opponent was trying to tell you.

Comment: A more common situation where that rule comes into play is when someone plays several goals from their hand consecutively. This is _almost_ equivalent to playing one goal and discarding the others (assuming no Double Agenda in play) -- except that, if someone else happens to meet one of the intermediate goals, they've won and the game ends.